# Database Table Normalization (3NF)

Tags: database, database-normalization, 3nf

```
| MatrikelNr [PK] | Stud.-Name | Klausur | Raum |
```

Matrikelnr = student number, Klausur = Exam name, Raum = Room.

I should get this table into 3NF, and write them as relations with primary keys underlined.

My solution:

```
Student (Matrikelnr, Stud.-Name)
Klausur (Matrikelnr, Klausur, Raum)
```

But my friend said the solution is:

```
Student (Matrikelnr, Stud.-Name, Klausur)
Klausur (Klausur, Raum)
```

Comment: Presumably a student can take many exams, a room can host multiple exams (possibly at different times)? You need to consider the cardinality of these relationships and model them appropriately

Comment: This site is in English, use English, there is no reason for any other language here, don't expect/force every reader to translate.

Comment: Quote & source the algorithm/process you are following & show what is given including assumptions & the steps of your work. Clarify via edits, not comments. Delete & flag obsolete comments. [help] Pick tags by clicking on suggested tags & read the tag wiki/info before you click.

Answer (score 1):

`Student` should only have student information.
`Student(Matrikelnr,Stud.-Name)`

`Exam` should only have exam information.
`Klausur(Klausur,Raum)`

Then you will need a table to hold the many-to-many relationship (student can take many exams, and an exam is taken by many students)

`StudentExam(StudentId, ExamId)`, both columns are the primary key from the other 2 tables.